# Json + java, cannot get an item

Tags: java, json

I do not manage to get the latitude, longitude from the following json (hold in json variable) I get from a http request:

```
{
  "name": "rue de la paix, paris, france",
  "Status": {
    "code": 200,
    "request": "geocode"
  },
  "Placemark": [ {
    "id": "p1",
    "address": "Rue de la Paix, 75002 Paris, France",
    "AddressDetails": {
   "Accuracy" : 6,
   "Country" : {
      "AdministrativeArea" : {
         "AdministrativeAreaName" : "Ile-de-France",
         "SubAdministrativeArea" : {
            "Locality" : {
               "LocalityName" : "Paris",
               "PostalCode" : {
                  "PostalCodeNumber" : "75002"
               },
               "Thoroughfare" : {
                  "ThoroughfareName" : "Rue de la Paix"
               }
            },
            "SubAdministrativeAreaName" : "Paris"
         }
      },
      "CountryName" : "France",
      "CountryNameCode" : "FR"
   }
},
    "ExtendedData": {
      "LatLonBox": {
        "north": 48.8724046,
        "south": 48.8661093,
        "east": 2.3343785,
        "west": 2.3280833
      }
    },
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": [ 2.3312296, 48.8692714, 0 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

I first get the "Placemark" JSONArray with the following code:

```
JSONArray array = json.optJSONArray("Placemark");
```

That is ok.
But I cannot get the "Point" object...

```
JSONObject coordinates_json_obj = json.optJSONArray("Placemark").getJSONObject(4);

 => JSONArray[4] not found.
```

Would you have any clue ?
Thanks a lot,
Luc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one object in the Placemark array. Point is an entry in that object.

Do this, maybe:

```
JSONObject coordinates_json_obj = json.optJSONArray("Placemark").get(0).getJSONObject("Point");
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get the city and country but unable to iterate through the response. Any pointers?

Comment: I have tried this but without any luck:
JSONArray Placemark = obj.getJSONArray("Placemark"); 
JSONObject j=Placemark.getJSONObject(0); 
String details=j.getString("Country");
But this doesnt work :(